# getDerivedStateFromProps() overrides setstate value in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I'm working with react class based component.I'm sending props to child component to show the data in table  .Inorder to receive props and set the state in child I'm making use of getDerivedStateFromProps().on pagination in child component it set the state but it is overrided by getDerivedStateFromProps().

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state){
          state.data=props.userData;
          state.loading=props.loading;
          state.current=props.pageNo;
}
setPaginationData(page, pagesize) {
        const prevPage=this.state.current;
        this.setState({loading: true});
        this.setState({current:page});    
         Users.getUser(page, true).then(res => {
          console.log(res);
          if(res===null){

            this.setState({current:prevPage});

          } else{
              this.setState({
                data: res
               });
        }       });
}
render(){
 return(
    <div>
    <Pagination
       current={this.state.current}
       total={this.state.data.totalRecords}
       pageSize={10}
       onChange={this.setPaginationData}
       >                                     
    </Pagination>
    <Table
        loading={this.props.loading}
        rowKey={data => data.ID}
        columns={this.columns1}
        rowSelection={this.rowSelection}
        childrenColumnName="users"
        onExpand={this.onExpand}
        dataSource={this.state.data ? this.state.data.accounts : []}
       /> 
      </div> 
}
```

How to avoid this issue please help

Comment: did anyone's comments help?

Answer (score 1):

The method should return object

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
  // also I recommend you to make the condition when to change state
  // or return null
  if (
    props.userData !== state.data ||
    props.loading !== state.loading ||
    props.pageNo !== state.current
  ) {
    return {
      data: props.userData,
      loading: props.loading,
      current: props.pageNo
    }
  }

  return null;
}
```

> getDerivedStateFromProps is invoked right before calling the render
>   method, both on the initial mount and on subsequent updates. It should
>   return an object to update the state, or null to update nothing.

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops

Comment: do you use condition? in the method I added

Answer (score 0):

`getDerivedStateFromProps` should return a new state object. e.g. 
`return {loading, current: pageNo}` from `getDerivedStateFromProps`

You're trying to set the value of state directly.

Also you have multiple `setState`s consecutively in `setPaginationData`
You will need just one as they are asynchronous, e.g.

`this.setState({loading: true,current:page});`

Comment: I didn't get what you said.Every time I set the setstate  getDerivedstatefromProps called

Comment: setting the state will cause a rerender which  in turn will trigger a new invocation of `getDerivedstatefromProps `

Comment: then how to set new state on pagination

Comment: well I think you do actually want this component to re-render, because the pagination has changed, so its a good thing